# syntax error near unexpected token `do' when run with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, watchdog

From here: http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/psc/watchdog/watchdog-testing.html

`for n in $(seq 1 60); do echo $n; sleep 1; sync; done`

I get:

```
:~$ sudo for n in $(seq 1 60); do echo $n; sleep 1; sync; done  
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell parses the command line and because `for` looks like an argument to `sudo`, you basically get a `do` without a `for`.

To fix it, run the loop in a subshell, either as a separate script, or like this;

```
sudo sh -c 'for n in $(seq 1 60); do echo "$n"; sleep 1; sync; done'
```

Better yet, avoid running anything unnecessary as a privileged user:

```
for n in $(seq 1 60); do echo "$n"; sleep 1; sudo sync; done
```

The first `sudo` will require a password, but subsequent iterations should have it cached, with the default settings on most distros.

If you are on Bash, you can use `{1..60}` instead of `$(seq 1 60)`. Obviously, if you want to use Bash-specific syntax inside the single quotes in the first example, you need `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`

Answer (score 2):

`for` is an internal function (not to be confused with functions) of a shell that's why you can't call it. You should explicitly call the binary of the shell that runs with the code like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'for n in $(seq 1 60); do echo "$n"; sleep 1; sync; done'
```

With bash:

```
sudo bash -c 'for n in {1..60}; do echo "$n"; sleep 1; sync; done'
sudo bash -c 'for ((n = 1; n <= 60; ++n)); do echo "$n"; sleep 1; sync; done'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the fist semicolon terminates the `sudo` command, which will make `do` a new command. The easiest way to fix this is to put the loop inside a file and execute it, like

```
sudo /bin/bash ./myfile
```

Comment: I am talking about the terminal command. where should the ; be placed?

Comment: When using `sudo` you can't have commands which requires embedded semicolons.