# Batch .SRT Rip Using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

I have this command using ffmpeg

```
root@ubuntu-4cpu-8gb-sg-sin1:/home/jaac/torrents/rtorrent/dots# ffmpeg -i Title.NF.WEB-DL.DDP2.0.x264-Ao.mkv -map 0:7 indo16.srt
```

That will rip 1 sub (Indonesia region)

How to rip it in batch? I have 17 files in dots folder

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Hi, I want to rip all Indonesian subtitle in folder dots. The command I post is for 1 file. I need a command that would do rip all the subtitles in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
cd /home/jaac/torrents/rtorrent/dots
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:s:m:language:ind "${f%.*}.srt"; done
```

Adapted from [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)

What the `-map` option is doing: `0:s:m:language:ind` is `input #0: subtitles:metadata:language:indonesian`. Which means it chooses all subtitle streams from the input that have Indonesian language metadata.

If you get error:

```
Stream map '0:s:m:language:ind' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
```

You can ignore it. Just a message telling you there is no subtitle stream with Indonesian language metadata in that particular input.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I got error -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
. Do I need to includer the ";?

Comment: @jaac You are using Linux? What is the output of `echo "$SHELL"`?

Comment: Yes I'm using Ubunto 16.
The output from echo "$SHELL" is /bin/bash

Comment: Modify the command to 



Thanks guys for helping me out.

I use this command to batch rip the subtitle:

#!/bin/bash
cd /home/jaac/torrents/rtorrent/dots || exit
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:5:s:m:language:id "${f%.*}.srt"; done

Comment: @jaac If you only want stream `0:5` specifically, then just use `-map 0:5`. You don't need `:s:m:language:id`. My example automatically chooses the subtitle stream that has Indonesian language metadata. So you don't need to know the stream index number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i $f -vf subtitles="${f%.mkv}".srt "${f%.mp4}"_sub.mkv; done
```

Subtitules files must have the same name as videos.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I got this error -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: Try this:
sh -c 'for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i $f -vf subtitles="${f%.mkv}".srt "${f%.mp4}"_sub.mkv; done'
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175596/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-do-when-run-with-sudo

Comment: I got this

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'


This is weird.

Can you please give the command step by step? I really new to this CLI. Thanks.

Comment: For me, it's fine. Are you using "sudo" before the command? I don't know what is the reason for the error. Try inserting the code into a sh file and run: bash script_name.sh. I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for helping me out.

I use this command to batch rip the subtitle:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/jaac/torrents/rtorrent/dots || exit
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:5:s:m:language:id "${f%.*}.srt"; done
```

I use  Shellcheck

Thanks @llogan and @m8factorial